# When should I (not) use the close option "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"?

Tags: support, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I've seen this close reason:

[image]

But if I click on it, I can only select Philosophy Meta. When should I use this option, and when not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This vote reason is there to automatically migrate questions to other sites. If you click on it, you will see a list of options.

There are simple rules:

1. If you think the question would fit on one of these sites, select it.
2. If you don't think the question would fit on any of these sites, **go back** and select another close reason. What you may do is use the 'Other' option, to add a comment suggesting migration to X.SE, and then after that flag the question for moderator attention.

At the moment only Meta is listed in the options. That does not mean that if you want to migrate [a question](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3134/2953) to Hinduism (e.g.), and it isn't in the list, you should just select Meta. It doesn't make sense to migrate the question to Meta, because it's off topic here (most of the questions on topic on Hinduism are off topic on Philosophy Meta). So, again, in this case you **go back** and **leave a comment** and potentially **flag** the question for moderator attention.

Comment: I believe that's a limitation of Beta SE sites. Mature SE sites show options for migration.